# How to query a database with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, sql-server

Using AngularJS, is it possible to query a database? Is there a best practice or preferred method for doing so?

I understand this can be done on a PHP Server, though what about a SQL Server?

Comment: browser has no way to communicate directly with a server side database. You would use `$http` which is angular's ajax api to communicate with  server side endpoint that would then communicate with database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to use data in Angular is to call your own web methods on your web server supporting the application. Those methods would then either call to SQL Server through code within that application or use other API's that would do those calls.

Even if you could, you would not want to do any kind of back-end call from the client.